# {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Tags: asp.net, sql, nullreferenceexception

Creating a ASP.NET form with C#, i am facing this error i don't know what is the error with it. Its all doing fine but when i push the save Button it gives me this error:

```
     NulllRefrenceException was unhandled by user code
    {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

### Code:

```
     protected void Button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
         cnn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlAddSave"].ConnectionString;
    cnn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from  DisplayPP";
    cmd.Connection = cnn;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, " DisplayPP ");
    SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
    DataRow drow = ds.Tables["DisplayPP"].NewRow();
    drow["website"] = web.Text;
    drow["country"] = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
    drow["contact"] = TextBox144.Text;
    drow["cat"] = TextBox145.Text;
    drow["traff"] = TextBox146.Text;

    more text boxes as above

    ds.Tables["DisplayPP "].Rows.Add(drow);
    da.Update(ds, " DisplayPP ");
    string script = @"<script language=""javascript"">
    alert('Information have been Saved Successfully.......!!!!!.');
   </script>;";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myJScript1", script);
    }
```

please help.

### Connection String:

```
<add name="sqlAddSave" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PPTableDisplay.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

### Exception

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user
>   code HResult=-2147467261 Message=Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. Source=TestCRole StackTrace: at
>   TestCRole._Default.Button8_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\WindowsAzure2\TestCRole\Default.aspx.cs:line 60 at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   InnerException:

Comment: **Where** do you get the error?

Comment: Use the debugger to find out what is null.

Comment: `TextBox146.Text` You should name your controls.

Comment: Please, put a breakpoint on the first line and debug step by step (using `F10`). This way you'll figure out which object, exactly, is not set.

Comment: @Slaks what you mean by TextBox146.Text should name your control ???

Comment: Before it was pointing to SQLConnection string now it gives error at:

  DataRow drow = ds.Tables["DisplayPP"].NewRow();

when i use breakpoint

Comment: Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=TestCRole
  StackTrace:
       at TestCRole._Default.Button8_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsAzure2\TestCRole\Default.aspx.cs:line 60
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:

Comment: @JohnKim I'm pretty sure he means that you should be naming your controls with names that make sense -> For example, instead of having a field called let's say `TextBox144` call it `ContactTextBox`, or you know something that would make more sense.

Comment: What's the exact line that throws the exception ? Can you include it in your question ?

Comment: @Dimitar Dimitrov , i have 500 Fields to do so i am pretty quick as no one needs to see those i know how to handle that but please if you can help just help resolving my error. :)

Comment: ERROR LINE:
    DataRow drow = ds.Tables["DisplayPP"].NewRow();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ds.Tables["DisplayPP "].Rows.Add(drow);
```

should be this

```
ds.Tables["DisplayPP"].Rows.Add(drow);
```

Comment: He's having the exception thrown before this line.

Comment: @Dimitar Dimitrov he is correct i was having same point error.

Comment: @JohnKim Oh, well, you said different in your comments :) Nevermind

Comment: Thanks mate ! I fixed that as it was same creating error in sqlconneciton string before.. well i have to add ID also ?? do I ?? means ID is auto generated so i left it as it was.. and got that error:

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'C:\USERS\XXXXXXX\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2012\PROJECTS\WINDOWSAZURE2\TESTCROLE\APP_DATA\PPTABLEDISPLAY.MDF.dbo.DisplayPP'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: Is your Id column supposed to be an identity but you don't have it set as such?  If you don't set the identity property it won't autopopulate the field when you add a record and this error will occur

Comment: yea i need it that way @b_richardson.   oh.. so how to fix this.. please a example will be great.. i am not just learning .net please help

Comment: Well I would suggest that if you can't autopopulate the identity column in the database for some reason then make that column a uniqueidentifier data type and then you can do something like: drow["Id"] = Guid.NewGuid() in your code.

Comment: Got my answer :) Thanks anyway :)

Comment: One last question my this query is not working:

 string script = @"<script language=""javascript"">
        alert('Information have been Saved Successfully.......!!!!!.');
       </script>;";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myJScript1", script);